# 2d rotation as complex operator - eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

All started from calculating exponent of 2x2 rotation matrix. One way to do it is to represent rotation as multiplication on some complex number $\lambda = e^{i\phi}, \phi = 2\pi/n$. Calculate its exponent and then again rewrite the resulting $e^\lambda$ number as matrix. This seems to be clear.

Now, what I find confusing is that for the operator $Az = \lambda z$ has all the complex line as a eigenspace. Suppose that some vecor $v$ is its basis. It follows that the operator in $\mathbb R^2$ should have an invariant line (in the deriction of this vector), which is wrong in general case.

I know that if we look at the complexified operator matrix instead we'll get what we want - two conjugated eigenvectors, but what is wrong about above reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track over what field you consider your vector space. When you say "the operator $Az=\lambda z$ has all the complex line as a eigenspace", you consider the complex line as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (1-dimensional). But when you look at it as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (2-dimensional), the corresponding operator does not have eigenspaces anymore (unless $\phi = \pi k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\lambda = \pm 1$).

When you look at the complex line as a 1-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, any two non-zero vectors are proportional. So any non-zero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, since $Av$ and $v$ are proportional. When you look at the complex line as a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, there are non-proportional vectors, and $Av$ and $v$ don't have to be 'real-proportional', even though they are 'complex-proportional'.

Comment: It's not really about dimesion but invariant spaces. If we have two conjugate eignevectors we have invariant plane (and we'll have it if we really take complexification of the initial rotation operator). I want to understand the link between eigenspace of this $\lambda z$ operator and initial one. What is related in $\mathbb R^2$ to this eigenvector?

Comment: Nothing. It is a linear combination of basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with complex coefficients, so it does not lie in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (That is, if the eigenvector you are asking about is one of the two conjugate eignevectors you mention above.)

Comment: We have 3 different operators acting on 3 different spaces: We have the original rotation operator $R$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. We have the operator $Az=\lambda z$ on $\mathbb{C}^1$. And we have the complexification $R_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $R$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$. Any non-zero vector of $\mathbb{C}^1$ is an eigenvector of $A$. These eigenvectors correspond to all non-zero vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but those corresponding vectors are not eigenvectors of $R$. The eigenvectors of $R_{\mathbb{C}}$ do not correspond to anything in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since they're lin. comb. of basis vec. with compl. coef.

Comment: Probably we don't understand each other. So let me present motivation from $\mathbb R^3$. Here we have every rotation has an axis and the plane orthogonal to it is 2-dimentional invariant plane being intersection with $\mathbb R^3$ of the plane spaned by two conhugated complex eigenvectors. The same for 2-dim rotations if we look at the matrix as complex one. 
As for my question it was about if we don't look at the rotation matrix as complex but make something a bit different, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the source of confusion. Actually here are two different operations - complexification ($\mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb C^2$) and "realification" ($\mathbb C \mapsto \mathbb R^2$). Important part is that they are not the inverse of one another and provide a bit different geometrical interpretation. In case of complexification the invariant plane is an intersection real plane and a span of two conjugated eigenvectors ($\mathbb R^2 \cap \langle \frac{x + \overline{x}}{2},  \frac{x - \overline{x}}{2i} \rangle$). Otherwise it's the "realification" of one-dimetional complex eigenspace, i.e. real plane. I think this idea works.